# Cant load Windows after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I installed Ubuntu in a computer with Windows 8. Now the grub 2.02 shows this options:

- Ubuntu
- Advanced options for Ubuntu
- Windows Boot Manager (/dev/sda2)
- System setup

If a select Ubuntu it works but when selecting Windows Boot Manager (/dev/sda2), Windows doesn't load and appears a black screen.

If a enter System setup, this is the configuration:

-Secure Boot: Disabled
-Secure Boot Status: Disabled
 -Boot mode: UEFI

This photo shows my partitions 
[Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlDru.png)

The thing is that I was able to boot Windows at first but I do not know why, I can not boot it know. Does anyone know what could be happening?

Comment: Did you leave Fast start up or the always on hibernation on. Grub will not boot a hibernated Windows, or one needing chkdsk. Since UEFI system, you should be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI or one time boot key, often f10 or f12, but varies, check your manual.

Comment: I left fast startup on. I can boot windows but it appears a black screen and it does not load anything.

Comment: If directly booting Windows from UEFI does not work that is a Windows issue. Can you press f8 and get into repair console. If totally broken you probably need to use your Windows repair flash drive (you did make one?) to fix Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try live boot again and connect to internet

and install boot-repair

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair